How to get snippets using Xcode Trailing Closure Syntax instead of parameters?
I've seen other posts in reddit and StackOverflow asking for the same, and accepted answers claim that pressing enter gets the job done, but I don't seem to get it working?
Xcode: Version 15.4 (15F31d)
I'd like to use closure trailing syntax (ideally by default, but it wouldn't bother me too much if I have to do it with extra keys)
So that when I type VStack and I select the option of alignment and content

Then the snippet that appears already uses closure trailing syntax.

Instead, what I get is the following snippet:


I've tried to press Enter twice and that interacts with the first parameter, alignment.
I've tried to fill the alignment, then press tab and when the focus is on the Text placeholder, press enter. It accepts the placeholder
I've tried to double click the blue highlighted Text("Placeholder") and it accepts it instead of changing the syntax


After you get
VStack(alignment: .center, content: {
    Text("Placeholder")
})

simply control click on content and choose Refactor -> Convert to Trailing Closure.

Another approach is to work from the inside out. Start with
Text("Placeholder")

Now select that and choose Embed In VStack from the contextual menu, which gives
VStack {
    Text("Placeholder")
}

Now if you want to change the alignment explicitly, use the Inspector.
Of course, if you don't like either of those solutions, nothing stops you from writing yours own custom Text Snippet.
